# Instance variable value in two objects of the same class (Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, variables, object

I am new at Objective C and ay programmer's world in general (2 or 3 weeks). Also I am Italian, and so It's quite difficult for me using english and the right terminology.

I created a class: "Mano" (Hand) with its instances and methods: m1 and m2.

My question is: How can I do to read m1 variables value with m2 ?

m1 and m2 have for example "int a; a=0;"

then m1, executing a method, sets a = 10

how can m2 read m1's a? Becouse if m2 simply reads a it reads his own a ... a=0, right?

Sorry again but I don't know how to explain myself better than this!

Comment: Please can you share all your code.

Comment: Yes! Of Course I can do! I will post my code tomorrow but It's a very bad code! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Same as you would if they were not the same kind of object, basically.  First, make what you want to read public:

```
//  Hand.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Hand : NSObject

// Each hand maintains a value
@property (assign) int a;

// This makes it easy to show two Hands working together...not necesary
- (instancetype)initAsFirst:(BOOL)first;
@end
```

Then, use a reference to one object from inside the other:

```
//  Hand.m
#import "Hand.h"

@implementation Hand

// To start, some other object will call this with first set to YES.
- (instancetype)initAsFirst:(BOOL)first
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        if (first) {

// The first Hand will create a second one to demonstrate the difference.
            self.a = 0;
            [self showHands:[[Hand alloc] initAsFirst:NO]];
        } else {

// The second Hand will have a different value to prove that it's different.
            self.a = 10;
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)showHands:(Hand *)h
{
// Display both the value of this hand (first) and the one this hand created (second)
    NSLog(@"Mine: %d, Other: %d", self.a, h.a);
}
@end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will study It tomorrow. Is it too annoying for you to comment a bit your code, please? :-) I am really two weaks old in programming! (I have just a few knowledge in basic!)

Comment: Sorry. I did not understand how I can set a=0 for first hand and a=10 for the second ... and hypothetically a=30 for a third hand... may be I am too old to learn!

Answer (score 0):

This was meant to be a simple RPS (Rock Paper Scissors) game just to start learning a little Objective C programming. In the beginning there were two objects m1 and m2 as the “Computer hand m1” and the “Player hand m2”.

Of course as you can see i joined the two methods (computer random number and human number choosing) so that all de job is made by just one object.

When methods were splitted I had problems  in the [verdetto] (game results) methods because of m2 (jn my case) were not able to get the right value of the object instance (i needed m1 values) …

and that’s why I asked you my question!

Here you have 0=Rock 1=Scissors 2=Paper

```
// File main.m

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "mano.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int contatore;
    contatore = 1;

    @autoreleasepool {

        mano *m1;
        m1 = [[ mano alloc ] init ];

        //  mano *m2;
        // m2 = [[ mano alloc ] init ]; 

        while (contatore <= 5) {
            NSLog(@"\n Partita N. %d", contatore);
            contatore++;
        [m1 gioco];
        [m1 controlloRisultato]; }
// [m1 generatoreRandom] RANDOM NUMBER GENERATOR to let the computer choose
// [m2 scelta numero]here the player was meant to choose bw 0,1,2.

        [m1 verdetto]; //game results 


    }

    return 0;
}




// File mano.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface mano : NSObject {


    NSArray *simboli; //Rock Scissors Paper
    NSInteger casuale; // Random Number
    NSInteger scelta; // Player Number
    NSInteger computer; // CPU wins
    NSInteger giocatore; // Player Wins
    NSInteger pareggi; // Draws

    }

- (void) gioco;
- (void) controlloRisultato;
- (void) verdetto;
// - (void) generatoreRandom
// - (void) scelta numero

@end




// File mano.m

#import "mano.h"

@implementation mano

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    casuale = 0;
    scelta = 0;
    simboli = [ [ NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Sasso",@"Forbici",@"Carta", nil]; //questo va nella init, giustamente, altrimenti non vale per tutti i metodi.
    return self; }

- (void) gioco {
    scelta =0;
    casuale =0;
    casuale = arc4random_uniform(3);  //il computer sceglie un numero

    // L'utente fa la sua scelta qui sotto
    do {
        NSLog (@"\n \n Inserisci 0 per Sasso, 1 per Forbici, 2 per Carta");
        scanf ("%ld", &scelta);
        if (scelta >2 || scelta <0) NSLog (@" \n Hai inserito un numero NON VALIDO");
    } while (scelta >2 || scelta <0);


}

- (void) controlloRisultato {

    NSLog(@"\nIl computer ha scelto: %@", [simboli objectAtIndex:casuale]);
    NSLog(@"\nTu hai scelto: %@", [simboli objectAtIndex:scelta ]);

    switch (casuale) {

        case (0):
            if (scelta == 0) {
                NSLog (@"\n È un pareggio!");
                ++pareggi;
                break;}

            else if (scelta == 1) {
                NSLog (@"\n Il Computer Vince!");
                ++computer;
                break;}

            else if (scelta == 2) {
                NSLog (@"\n Hai vinto!");
                ++giocatore;
                break;}

        case (1):
            if (scelta == 0) {
                NSLog (@"\n Hai Vinto!");
                ++giocatore;
                break;}

            else if (scelta == 1) {
                NSLog (@"\n È un pareggio!");
                ++pareggi;
                break;}

            else if (scelta == 2) {
                NSLog (@"\n Il computer Vince!");
                ++computer;
                break; }

        case (2):
            if (scelta == 0) {
                NSLog (@"\n Il computer Vince!");
                ++computer;
                break; }

            else if (scelta == 1) {
                NSLog (@"\n Hai Vinto!");
                ++giocatore;
                break; }

            else if (scelta == 2) {
                NSLog (@"\n È un pareggio");
                ++pareggi;
                break;}

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }


    }

- (void)verdetto {
    NSLog(@"\n Vittorie giocatore: %ld", giocatore);
    NSLog(@"\n Vittorie computer: %ld", computer);
    NSLog(@"\n Pareggi: %ld", pareggi);

    if (giocatore > computer) NSLog(@"\n Bravo! Hai vinto tu la partita!");
    else NSLog(@"\n Hai perso! Il computer ha vinto la partita");

}

@end
```

Comment: You were probably better off with your first approach.  The idea of two hands competing is a better match for how the game actually works.  Perhaps you need to set things up so that you can call `[m1 verdetto:m2];`.  That way you can reference both hands in the method...one would be `self` and the other the parameter.

Comment: Thanks for helping It's harder than I expected. I have to get the meaning of "self" better ... I will try to rewrite code from the start, so ... I will come back saying that I was not able! :) (and I just can't image what it would be with a "third hand"!! )

Comment: If you're starting over, my advice is to create software objects that mimic the objects in the real world as much as possible.  If there are two real hands, there should be two software hands.  A real hand doesn't decide whether it has won or not, something outside the hands compares them and decides.  Etc.

Comment: yes ... I was meant to create one "hand" class and two objects and to leave the control to a method. I never thought about creating two classes .. one for "human" hand and the other for "computer" hand! :)

Comment: Well, a computer hand and a human hand could be two objects of the same type with different ways of setting the value or you could have a super-class of 'Hand' and sub-classes of 'ComputerHand' and 'HumanHand'.  If you make them different classes, having a common parent class would be useful when comparing.

Comment: P.S. Now I get what you mean! Creating a new class for compare and decide ... but I always have to "read" hand variables form the outside, and at the moment is what I am trying to learn! :-) Thank you for your suggestions! I will try with sub classes !!!

Comment: If you look again at my sample code, that's the role of `self.a` and `h.a`.  (Public variables.)

Comment: Yes ... But I'm having some problems in understanding how to use `self.a` and `h.a`

Answer (score 0):

now I have 1 class

```
@interface mani : NSObject
```

that maybe could control the game result.

and 2 subclasses:

```
@interface computer : mani //for random number generator

@interface giocatore : mani //for player choosing number
```

Now the matter for me is letting the first class (mani) read its subclasses variables, and do what to do to determine who is the winner! Still can't get how it works, and belive me, I am reading forums, and e-books!